# HTTPS on Wordpress hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, https, wordpress, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to force https over HTTP protocol for my website. I have managed to force the `http://example.com` => `https://example.com` and all blog post URLs.

However, when I try to access `https://example.com/wp-admin`, it says `example.com` redirected you too many times. `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Please note that:

- My local development and AWS Elastic Beanstalk are connected to the same database.
- `localhost` and `localhost/wp-admin` works fine and can log in to admin panel successfully.
- I have setup an environment variable `WP_ENV` to determine if it is a local or production environment.

Here is my setup of my `wp-config.php` file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

/** HTTPS  */
if (getenv('WP_ENV') == 'production'){
    define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
    define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
}

if(getenv('WP_ENV') == 'development'){
    /* Http only.  */
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost');
}
```

And here is my .htacess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
# For a site running on port 80 (http)
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^wp-(admin|login|register)(.*) https://example.com/wp-$1$2 [L]
</If>

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Cross-site post on StackOverflow by a different user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598059/https-on-wordpress-hosted-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk (?)